# NullPointerException on "getContext().getString(resId);"

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, ocr, crashlytics

I am a student working on a school project on Android OCR. Currently, I have successfully completed the OCR function in Android Studio 1.5.

However, I wanted to compile this app(non-Material theme) into another app(with Material theme design) also in Android Studio.

I have copied and refined most of the codes appropriately. However when I run the app on my device, it crashed at a certain point.

I have implemented Crashlytics in my application and it shows the following error:

[image]

The following is the logcat information:

```
    Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.l33902.contactmanagment1512/com.example.l33902.contactmanagment1512.ShowImage}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getString(int)' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2546)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2754)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5938)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getString(int)' on a null object reference
       at com.example.l33902.contactmanagment1512.AndrOCRApp.myGetString(AndrOCRApp.java:22)
       at com.example.l33902.contactmanagment1512.ShowImage.<init>(ShowImage.java:40)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1650)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2536)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2754)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5938)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
```

According to Crashlytics and Logcat, I can see that the error is caused by a NullPointerException. However, when I drill down to the codes as stated by the logcat that caused the error, I could not figure out how to solve it.

As stated by Crashlytics and Logcat, the root of the problem belongs in these 2 files (AndrOCRApp.java and ShowImage.java)(Below are the codes):

**- AndrOCRApp.java**

```
public class AndrOCRApp extends Application {

    private static AndrOCRApp s_instance;

    public AndrOCRApp ()
    {
        s_instance = this;
    }

    public static Context getContext()
    {
        return s_instance;
    }

    public static String myGetString(int resId)
    {
        **return getContext().getString(resId);**       
    }

}
```

**- ShowImage.java**

**`private final String[] mSegModeArray = {
    AndrOCRApp.myGetString(R.string.PSM_AUTO),
    AndrOCRApp.myGetString(R.string.PSM_SINGLE_BLOCK),
    AndrOCRApp.myGetString(R.string.PSM_SINGLE_LINE),
    AndrOCRApp.myGetString(R.string.PSM_SINGLE_WORD),
    AndrOCRApp.myGetString(R.string.PSM_SINGLE_CHAR),
    AndrOCRApp.myGetString(R.string.PSM_SINGLE_BLOCK_VERT_TEXT)
};`**

The **bolded** lines are the codes that caused the error.

The error states that attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getString(int)' is on a null object reference.

However, I could not resolve this error as the previous original project(before compiling) did not show such error.

Any help/solutions with be greatly appreciated~

Comment: Using this kind of code, the problem is you don’t know where that Context came from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your problem is here:

```
public AndrOCRApp ()
{
    s_instance = this;
}
```

You should not use a custom constructor for things like `Application`, `Activity`, `Fragment` or any other Android framework object that has a lifecycle controlled by the system. Instead, override the lifecycle method you need. In this case you should assign `s_instance` in the `onCreate` lifecycle method of your Application class.

Comment: Thanks for your response, greatly appreciated. I have attempted several methods from your suggestion and been searching for similar tutorials online. But it still does not work out. Is it possible for you to provide an example?

Comment: Just remove your constructor and override the `onCreate` method and put `s_instance = this;` in there. Have a look at the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate() . Also make sure your application is declared in the manifest or else it will never be instantiated by the system.

Comment: Thanks:) However I solved it just by adding this line: "android:name="com.example.l33902.contactmanagment1512.AndrOCRApp"" under <application> tag in my manifest file. Will accept yours as the answer anyways ~

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here.

```
return getContext().getString(resId);
```

You should use with your application class `instance`

```
return s_instance.getContext().getString(resId);
```

Comment: Tried it. However, it still shows the same error. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
getResources().getString(resId);
```